# Azure Functions using Azure Hybrid Connections

Tags: azure, azure-functions, hybrid-cloud, azure-hybrid-connections

Is it possible to use Azure Hybrid Connections from the Azure Functions app service?  The networking option appears to be missing from the routing section of the settings for the Functions service.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't currently work for dynamic Function Apps, but should work for dedicated Function Apps.

Comment: Even creating a dedicated / classic function app, Hybrid Connections are not available. Is this a limitation with Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2):

I had to specify **App Service Plan** vs Consumption Plan (the current default) as the Hosting Plan setting for the Function App for any of the Networking features to show up (see screenshot below).

This wasn't mentioned in the other top search hits I ran into. Took a lucky guess after seeing other networking bits mentioned on [learn.microsoft.com page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

I couldn't see how to change this setting on a Function App after the fact, had to delete and recreate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your Function
2. Select the "Platform features" tab
3. Click "Networking..." under the "Networking" heading
4. A pop-up menu will show to the right, the second option down is "Hybrid Connections"